# How can I get list of all ec2 instances created by an IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have an AWS account with many IAM user. There are some ec2 instances which are not tagged. How can I get list of all ec2 instances created by an IAM user ?

Comment: You might want to send an email to the individuals that have EC2 launch privileges in this account and tell them that they have 48 hours to correctly tag their resources, before an automated reaper process will identify untagged resources and do unspecified bad things to them.

Comment: I'd suggest using AWS Athena to check for `RunInstances` API call with username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no direct way to find the owner of the instance. Here is the Python Boto3 script which I use.

List all the instances and does API call to cloudtrail to find out who started(ec2:RunInstances) the instance.

https://gist.github.com/sudharsans/39d5eaf8a82b7ccdf8b3230d13ba7d81

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use [CloudTrail](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/cloudtrail/). All API calls will be logged there, along with access keys identifying the principal that invoked the API. CloudTrail is enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

In the AWS Management console you can use [Tag Editor](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsconsolehelpdocs/latest/gsg/tag-editor.html) to [search for resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsconsolehelpdocs/latest/gsg/searching-resources-to-tag.html) that are not tagged:

> (Optional) In the next Tags box, do any of the following:
>
> Leave the box empty to search for all resources with the specified key
>   and any value.
>
> Select **Not tagged** to search for resources that do not have the
>   specified tag key.
>
> Select **Empty** value to search for resources that have the specified tag
>   key but no value.

Comment: While this is a helpful technique to identify untagged EC2 instances, it does not address the core question which is how to identify who launched those EC2 instances.